# Прыжок по неровной поверхности

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема заключается в том, на некоторых поверхностях не прыгает игрок ( Например: Встав по центру куба 1х1 он прыгает, отойти на 1 юнит в сторону игрок не прыгает) Как это исправить? 
Код в придачу:

```
private void OnJump()
{
    if (_isGrounded == true)
    {
        deltaY = 0.0f;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            deltaY = jumpForce;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        deltaY -= fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

private void OnCheckGrounded()
{
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);
    RaycastHit hit;
    float distanceToHit = 1.1f;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distanceToHit))
    {
        _isGrounded = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверь размеры своего триггера

Comment: Размеры триггера равны размеру Капсулы(Игрока)

Comment: Проблема не в коде, а в размерах

Comment: Даже изменяя поверхность Terrain-а, на не ровной поверхности он не прыгает.

Comment: Где у вас переменная `_isGrounded` меняется? Лучше покажите этот часть.

Comment: Проверите код еще раз.